# What does "posthumous perfume" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am reading book *Lolita* and  I am having trouble with understanding the phrase "posthumous perfume":

> My work had begun to interest me again. I mean my scholarly exertions; the other thing, my active participation in my uncle’s **posthumous perfumes**, had by then been cut down to a minimum.

Comment: I have never read _Lolita_ but I have seen that Humbert Humbert's uncle had left him part of his estate on condition that he moved to the US and took an interest in the uncle's business. I assume that the uncle was a perfumier who had left the formulae of developed perfumes that had never been put into production or released. These perfumes would be _postumous perfumes_ in the same way as novels published after an author's death are called _posthumous_.

Comment: Of course as Humbert worked through the _posthumous perfumes_ the amount of work remaining to be done would decrease as Humber had no interest in, or probably talent for, for inventing new ones.

Comment: Wou man,  good explanation. my native language is not english probably that is  why i am having trouble,  though i  have read plenty of books in english.

Comment: I guess from your response that my suggestion fits in with what you have read previously in the book. Did you either understand or look up 'posthumous' before you posted the question?

Comment: I knew what posthumous mean and as well perfume, but   i didn't understand the phrase together.

Comment: Don't worry, "posthumous perfumes" isn't a phrase I'd ever seen before, Nabokov will have invented it. It's very clever though, it extends the idea of posthumous publication to the realm of perfumery and made me realise that there are aspects of the process of bringing a perfume to production and marketing which are close analogues of the process of publishing a work of literature or music.